# Is that a feature or a bug of clang c++11 std::regex_match?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, clang++

I noted that a regular expression, containing two patterns with OR condition, do not match a sample string if the first pattern is a beginning part of the second pattern (tested on clang 3.5 and clang 3.8):

```
std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(ab|a)")) == true
```

but

```
std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(a|ab)")) == false
```

I think `true` is logically correct in both cases.

Clang & OSX:

```
$ cat > test.cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(a|ab)")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(ab|a)")) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
^C

$ clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ clang++ ./test.cpp -o test

$ ./test 
0
1
```

Clang & FreeBSD:

```
$ cat > test.cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(a|ab)")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(ab|a)")) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
^C
$ clang++ -v
FreeBSD clang version 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final 262564) (based on LLVM 3.8.0)
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd11.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
$ clang++ ./test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
0
1
```

Linux & GCC:

```
$ cat > test.cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(a|ab)")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(ab|a)")) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
^C

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.1 20160904 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 

$ g++ -std=gnu++11 ./test.cpp -o test

$ ./test 
1
1
```

Comment: [GCC 6.3 test](https://ideone.com/gUm6cL) returns 1 for both.

Comment: [gcc 5.4.0 test returns 1 for both too.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0T73YQHHS3viGIzk)

Comment: Why would *((std::regex_match("ab", std::regex("(a|ab)")) == false))* be  *0*?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub "ab" matchs the second pattern of "(a|ab)"

Comment: You think `true` is logically correct in both cases, but you expect 1 and 0? (Maybe it is just a bit confusing whether you consider the `== false` part as part of your logical expression, which neither of @WiktorStribiżew or @JasonR did in their examples)

Comment: @Max Fomichev, And they do. So what's the question?

Comment: This is [LWG issue 2273](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2273).

Comment: @T.C. thanks a lot, it's very interesting discussion (but without a final answer).

Comment: The answer is there, but I suppose a little opaque to someone unfamiliar with the standard committee's workings. I'll write an answer when I get some time, if no one else get to it first.

Comment: @T.C. waiting for your answer. By the way, MSVS2015 result is 1 and 1, so it looks like there is only one exception in the stadart interpretation - Clang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ECMAScript (the default regex syntax) attempts to match the alternatives in order, stopping at the first success, which means that in ordinary searching (a la `regex_search`) the regex `a|ab` never matches the whole `ab`; it always matches just the `a` part.

The standard was ambiguous about what `regex_match` was supposed to do in this case, leading to implementation divergence. See [LWG issue 2273](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2273) for the competing interpretations. Eventually the standard was amended (see the resolution of that issue) to make clear that `regex_match` only considers potential matches that match the entire input sequence, as the example added to the standard makes clear:

```
std::regex re("Get|GetValue");
std::cmatch m;
regex_search("GetValue", m, re);    // returns true, and m[0] contains "Get"
regex_match ("GetValue", m, re);    // returns true, and m[0] contains "GetValue"
```

The original `<regex>` implementation in libc++ used the other interpretation, however, and it simply wasn't updated to match the resolution until [recently](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=285352). Clang 4.0 now prints `1 1`.